# What are "excess deaths"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Study Claims Iraq's **'Excess' Death** Toll Has Reached 655,000

Read more: http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2006/10/10/AR2006101001442.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excess deaths generally means over and above those that would have died anyway - the normal mortality rate for that population. The assumption being that those are the deaths you can blame on the war.

Comment: Your answer can also be applied in this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraq_War where it says "Estimated excess deaths"

Answer (score 3):

This is not a common usage.  For once the journalists make it relatively clear what they mean in the body of the article; the number of deaths in Iraq in the last year, as estimated by this study, that *exceed* the official estimates.